# EF6 code first - Identity is unique combinaison of two column in table

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Good morning,

I am using EF6 code first and I try to achieve the following :

I have a class/table Fighter:

```
public class Fighter
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FighterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to keep track of the different number of wins between the fighters so I created an other class: FightResult

```
public class FightResult
{
    public virtual Fighter Fighter1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Fighter Fighter2{ get; set; }
    public uint Wins1 { get; set; }
    public uint Wins2 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the combinaisons of Fighter1 and Fighter2 to be unique.
For exemple let's say this entry already exists:

```
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
| Fighter1 | Fighter2 | Wins1 | Wins2 |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
| Jon Cena | Yoda     |     0 |     0 |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
```

I don't want to be able to enter an entry with the same fighters for example these two:

```
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
| Fighter1 | Fighter2 | Wins1 | Wins2 |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
| Jon Cena | Yoda     |     0 |     1 |
| Yoda     | Jon Cena |     0 |     0 |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
```

There is maybe a better way to handle this with Entity Framework, if you have a suggestion I would be happy to read it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write something like this (it will create composite primary key: Fighter1ID with Fighter2ID, I advice you to set keys with int type instead of string as you specify on picture, especially if Fighter class has int FighterId as shown above).

```
    public class FightResult {

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]        
        public int Fighter1ID { get; set; }        
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]        
        public int Fighter2ID { get; set; }        

        public virtual Fighter Fighter1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Fighter Fighter2{ get; set; }
        public uint Wins1 { get; set; }
        public uint Wins2 { get; set; }  
}
```

Then before you will add new items you can sort fighters by id, for example:

```
//You have two fighters: fighter1 and fighter2
var firstFighter = fighter1.ID > fighter2.ID ? fighter1 : fighter2;
var secondFighter = fighter1.ID > fighter2.ID ? fighter2 : fighter1;
db.FightResult.Add(new FightResult { Fighter1 = firstFighter, Fighter2 = secondFighter, Wins1 = 1, Wins2 = 0});
```

Also you can try another approach (I recommend you first one, because I think may be pitfals with second variant):

```
    public class FightResult {    
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]       
        public int ID {get; set;}

        public virtual Fighter Fighter1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Fighter Fighter2 { get; set; }
        public uint Wins1 { get; set; }
        public uint Wins2 { get; set; }

        public FightResult(Fighter Fighter1, Fighter Fighter2, uint Wins1, uint Wins2)
        {
            //1. Assign constructor arguments to corresponding instance fields
            //2. Generate uniq ID based on pair of fighters (independently on their order)
            ID = _generateID(Fighter1, Fighter2);
        }
 }
```